# ng-repeat array of collections to table cell not working

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean-stack

I have been designing a MEAN Stack application. I have the following mongoDB data.

**hostels**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e3c21c03d8d54b35af796ed"), 
   "Hostel" : "The traveler's Lodge", 
   "Rooms" : 23,  
   "Customer" : [ 
   {   "_id" : ObjectId("5e3c1e863d8d54b35af796eb"), 
       "name" : "Harry Williams", 
       "From" : "United States", 
       "numDays" : 12 
    }] 
}
```

I have been trying to print it into a table. However When trying to print the data within the array, I am unable to do so. I have tried using ng-repeat to do this but this just results in the table cell remaining blank.

**app.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let lodge of hostels>
    ...
    <td ng-repeat="arr in lodge.Customer">{{ arr.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone know why this is, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Why are you mixing `ng-repeat` (used in AngularJS 1.x) with `*ngFor` (used in Angular 2+)?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `arr in lodge.Customer`?

Comment: Try:

<tr *ngFor="let lodge of hostels>
    ...
    <td *ngFor="let cust  of lodge.Customer">{{ cust.name}}</td>
</tr>

Comment: @Joe Thank you, it should have been lodge, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix Angular 2+ and Angular 1.x
Try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let lodge of hostels>
    ...
    <td *ngFor="let arr of lodge.Customer">{{ arr.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your example. I needed it to be on the same td, however using a span fixed this issue.

Comment: Glad to help you.